# Dell Monitor | No HDMI signal from your device

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, dell, hdmi, external-monitor

I have an HDMI port on this PC and on **Dell P2417H Monitor**; they are plugged in.

---

There is no signal, and so the monitor "sleeps".

When I unplug the HDMI from PC side; monitor displays:

```
Scanning for signal...
```

Followed by:

```
No HDMI Cable
The display will go into Power Save Mode in 4 minutes.
www.dell.com/support/monitors
```

---

When I plug the HDMI back into the PC; monitor displays:

```
No HDMI signal from your device.
```

Followed by:

```
Entering Power Saving Mode.
```

---

Version:

```
me@me:~$ nmcli d wifi list
me@me:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`xrandr`:

```
me@me:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Comment: Any solution here from the author?

Comment: My only solution was to re-install Ubuntu. Not ideal, but that solves most problems. The initial install did not download external dependencies; I skipped passed those options. I also ensured to download and create the then latest image of Ubuntu OS

Comment: Since it was a re-install and not a solution for this problem, I decided not to make nor accept that as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today after my setup had been working without issue for months. I had disconnected my laptop to work from a different location and upon reconnecting, my laptop failed to recognize the same 2nd display it previously used, a Dell SE3223Q.

The solution was surprisingly simple. In the display configuration, select the Dell monitor in the 'Device' field, and checked the 'Enable' option. This as an option isn't immediately obvious, as it's not clear that there are additional items in the select list.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma 5.16.8. I hope this solution helps others facing a similar problem.